# Как сделать терминальный текстовый редактор

Tags: linux, c, консоль

хочу сделать текстовый редактор для linux (можно и для windows, пока не определился, но терминальный точно) на языке C. Был опыт создания текстового редактора на Python, но такой редактор я открывал как приложение. В случае с C хочу сделать терминальный текстовый редактор как nano. Как можно реализовать такую вещь: пользователь открыл терминал -> ввел, например, как в текстовом редакторе micro команду `./micro` и открылось в этом же терминале окно с текстовым редактором. Название библиотеки, может, статью какую-нибудь, буду благодарен.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: можешь начать гуглить со слова `ncurses`...

Comment: `хочу сделать терминальный текстовый редактор как nano` → [gnu/nano](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_nano) → [git](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/nano.git)

Comment: я думаю, это самый простой вариант для старта https://github.com/antirez/kilo

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin я имел ввиду сам формат - через терминал, а не сам nano

Comment: @KoVadim спасибо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я делал консольный текстовый редактор под Linux используя ncurses. А под Windows - pdcurses. Они отличаются некоторыми моментами, но по сути это одно и тоже. Научитесь использовать ncurses и с pdcurses проблем не будет, но все же почитайте в интернете об их различиях, иначе вас может ждать неприятный сюрприз.

EDIT:

> Как можно реализовать такую вещь: пользователь открыл терминал -> ввел, например, как в текстовом редакторе micro команду ./micro и открылось в этом же терминале окно с текстовым редактором. Название библиотеки, может, статью какую-нибудь, буду благодарен.

Если я правильно понял что вам нужно, то в том же линуксе вы можете запустить свой текстовый редактор из любого терминала используя [эту инструкцию](https://losst.ru/kak-zapustit-programmu-na-linux). А что бы создать новое окно в уже открытом текстовом редакторе в том же терминале, тут вам в помощь ncurses. Я не пользовался micro, потому не знаю что конкретно вы хотите сделать (может что-то специфичное). В худшем случае используя тот же ncurses вам придется достаточно много пописать ручками что бы разделить экран сохраняя при этом все требования что предъявляет ваша программа.

Comment: Микро работает как нано в линуксе. Вводишь команду ./micro и включается текстовый редактор

Comment: На всякий случай http://helpexe.ru/kak/kak-sdelat-programmu-ispolnjaemoj-iz-ljubogo-mesta

Comment: спасибо, будет полезно

Comment: Очень краткое введение в ncurses: http://alexber220.narod.ru/ncurses/

Полная дока тут: https://tldp.org/HOWTO/NCURSES-Programming-HOWTO/index.html